# Association Object-Enum, which is more efficient?

Tags: java, arrays, enums, boolean

Let's say I have the following enum:

```
public enum Example{

A,
B,
C,
D,
E;

}
```

I need an association between an Object and the enum above.
In my specific case, one object must have only one `Example` association, except for `Example.B` and `Example.C`, because an Object could eventually have these two associations.

Right now my solution is: I have created an object wrapper of a five booleans, each boolean representing an enum. When it's true it means there is an association with the represented Example constant.

In the end I have an association between the Object and the Wrapper.
The thing is that I believe it's unnecessary to carry around these five booleans, because in most cases only boolean will be true and in very few cases only two booleans will be true. But never more than two.

Then I thought that maybe an association between an Object and an `ArrayList<Example>` would be more appropriate. Or maybe even better an array `Example[]` of size 2.

What do you think?

Please, if you have any different suggestions let me know.

Comment: Showing your code would make your question clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add a field of type `Set` to the class you like to associate with one or more `Example`s. Add those `Example` values to the set you like to associate your type with.

**Code Example**

```
public class MyObject {

    public static MyObject createAssociatedWithBAndC() {
        return new MyObject(Example.B, Example.C);
    }

    public static MyObject create(Example example) {
        return new MyObject(example);
    }

    private final Set<Example> examples = new HashSet<>();

    private MyObject(Example... examples) {
        for (Example example : examples) {
            this.examples.add(example);
        }
    }
}
```

And in case you really, really need to avoid using too much memory try it this way (reflecting your requirements) which uses `null` as *associated with B and C*:

```
public class MyObject {

    private final Example example;

    private MyObject(Example example) {
        this.example = example;
    }

    public Set<Example> getExamples() {
        return example == null
            ? EnumSet.of(Example.B, Example.C)
            : EnumSet.of(example);
    }
}
```

Now you hold only one or none `Example`s while none means: *associated with B and C*. And if instantiation the `EnumSet` is as well to expansive try:

```
public class MyObject {

    private final Set<Example> examples;

    private MyObject(Example example) {
        this.example = example == null
            ? EnumSet.of(Example.B, Example.C)
            : EnumSet.of(example);
    }

    public Set<Example> getExamples() {
        return examples;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, but like I said each Set would have either one element or two (in the case of Example.B and Example.C).
Anyway, may I ask you why you suggested a Set structure? Is more efficient than an ArrayList or an actual array?

Comment: No. But it makes clear you like to have only distinct `Examples`. Do you want to enforce the `1` or `2` example rule? And only if `B` or `C` is a member?

Comment: Are association with `B` only or `C` only allowed as well?

Comment: Oh, okay, in order to avoid same Examples in the Set.
I don't think I really need to enforce that rule, because right now my code, in case of an association of size 2, should generate only an association of B and C.
Yes, association with B only and C only are allowed as well.

Comment: Ok. And you are in search of an efficient solution in terms of memory footprint?

Answer (score 0):

Which is the goal to have `boolean` values to transform them into `Example` enum values ?

This is better :

> Then I thought that maybe an association between an Object and an
>   ArrayList would be more appropriate. Or maybe even better an
>   array Example[] of size 2.

However, array use has limitations. 
An array that has a variable size as in your case is harder to manipulate as you have to remember how many elements are effectively contained in (generally with a integer value). 
Besides, if the size of 2 always goes to 3, you have to change its declaration.

I would prefer a `List` implementation or a `Set` implementation as the enum are constant and unique values. You could use an `EnumSet` implementation.

You could instantiate them like that :

```
EnumSet<Example> examples = EnumSet.of(Example.A, Example.B);
```

Comment: Another user suggested to me an HashSet. What are the differences between an HashSet and an EnumSet? Probably with the HashSet guarantee to have different Example in the set?

Comment: No since a Set has no duplicated.  `EnumSet<Example> examples = EnumSet.of(Example.A, Example.A);` adds a single `A` value. The differences with Hashset ? It is designed for enum : addapted API to enums, size occupation and time processing  are more efficient. I invite you to read the doc about it.